# Why does returning a List from an out argument of type IEnumerable not return the items from the list?

Tags: c#, out

I found a peculiar issue which I cannot explain. I've found a workaround for the initial issue but would like to know why and how the following happens. Because I cannot explain this behavior even after looking at the docs.

**Initial issue**

I had a function which parses a csv files and returns a list of errors and/or parsed records via an out argument as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ParseCsv(string file, out IEnumerable<string> records)
{
    records = new List<string>();
    //... (actual parsing)
    records.Add("foo");
    records.Add("bar");

    return Enumerable.Empty<string>(); //Returning errors
}

//And calling the method:

IEnumerable<string> records;
ParseCsv("somefile.csv", out records);
//records yields zero records
```

**Workaround**

After making sure that the parse logic was working correctly I started to investigate further. My initial thought was that the value to the `out` variable was set immediately and any further calls would not modify the initial state set.
Later I found a workaround by marking the `out` argument as `IList<>` instead of `IEnumerable<>`. This disproved my initial thought because the list stays the same and the reference to this list seems to be pass out through the argument.

```
public IEnumerable<string> ParseCsv(string file, out IList<string> records)
{
    records = new List<string>();
    //... (actual parsing)
    records.Add("foo");
    records.Add("bar");

    return Enumerable.Empty<string>(); //Returning errors
}

//Calling:
IList<string> records;
ParseCsv("somefile.csv", out records);
```

**Explanation**

Now I cannot explain why this is happening because the reference seems to be pointing to the same list instance as initially set, why does enumerating it yield zero results when the `out` argument is not of type `IList<>`?

I would at least expect a runtime exception instead of this strange behavior.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's hard to see what's going on just from the snippets you've presented here. I wouldn't expect this code to even compile, given that `records` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, and that doesn't have an `Add` method.

Comment: Why do you return an IEnumerable if you want to use an out argument? Don't you rather want to return a bool to make sure the parsing was succesfull (and maybe call it TryParseCsv?)

Comment: @Icepickle Agreed that it would be better, but the goal is to get all errors in the file, not just validate it.

Comment: A simplified version of your first method works fine for me. Can you re-state the problem you're seeing? I have this method: `public static void test(out IEnumerable<string> output) { output = new List<string> {"one", "two"}; }` and I call it like this: `IEnumerable<string> records; test(out records);` and `records` has two items after the method returns.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just tried writing a complete example. And it indeed does not compile. It does compile in my current project however. I found there was a Extention method `.Add(...)` for `IEnumerable<T>` from some external package. This give me false indications that the code was correct.

Comment: So was that at the bottom of what was wrong? This sort of thing is precisely why it's worth writing a [mcve] for the very first version of your question.

Comment: Yes, I unintentionally skipped **Restart from scratch** part by creating my examples in my current project.

Answer (score 2):

The *declared type* of `records` is `IEnumerable<string>`. So even after you've assigned a `List<string>` to that variable, you can only (directly) call methods that are supported by the `IEnumerable<string>` interface.

There's no reason why you have to use *that particular variable* whilst you're creating and populating your list:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ParseCsv(string file, out IEnumerable<string> records)
{
    var results = new List<string>();
    records = results;
    //... (actual parsing)
    results.Add("foo");
    results.Add("bar");

    return Enumerable.Empty<string>(); //Returning errors
}
```

Comment: "you can only (directly) call methods that are supported by the IEnumerable<string> interface" yes this is indeed the case. I was fooled by an extension method `Add(...)` on `IEnumerable<T>` from an external package. I found this trying to create a working example outside of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert like this

```
List<string> recordsList = records.ToList();
```

Watch out for the `ArgumentNullException` if your IEnumarable is null